# kubernetes: Unable to get pod logs

Tags: amazon-web-services, logging, kubernetes, rancher

I have set up a k8s cluster via Rancher UI on `aws`.

I have deployed my app using several services and deployments.

However, I am completely unable to get access to the pod/container logs.

```
$ kubectl logs -f <pod_id>

Unable to connect to the server: EOF
```

What is more, when accessing the pod via the Kubernetes dashboard and clicking on the logs icon, I am transferred to an empty page.

Could it be a security groups configuration issue?

The instances are behind the default `rancher-machine` security group + I have allowed all traffic from my IP.

Comment: Try running it with `-v=10` to see more logs.